# I would like to ask about double clicked the data Gridview row then the code below layout

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

HTML CODE, this concept can work , but i need to apply it on my gridview table after data binded.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.clickme').click(function() {
            alert("Hello World");
        });
    });


 <tr class="clickme">
  <td>Shop: </td>
 </tr>
 <asp:GridView ID="dgMain" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ChassisNo" OnPageIndexChanging="dgMain_PageIndexChanging"
                      OnRowCreated = "OnRowCreated" CssClass="table table-bordered" CellPadding="6" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#eeeeee" OnSorting="Sorting">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateField>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:CheckBox id="chkSelection" runat="server" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="No" >
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label id="LabelNo" runat="server" >
                                    <%# GetIndex( DataBinder.Eval(Container, "RowIndex")) %>                                                                    
                                </asp:Label>                                                               
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="OperationName" HeaderText="Operation Name" SortExpression="OperationName"/>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="OperationStart" HeaderText="Operation Start" SortExpression="OperationStart"/>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="LOTNo" HeaderText="LOT No" SortExpression="LOTNo"/>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="MSC" HeaderText="MSC" SortExpression="MSC" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="MaterialGroup" HeaderText="Material Group" SortExpression="MaterialGroup"/>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="ChassisNo" HeaderText="Chassis No" SortExpression="ChassisNo" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="ColorID" HeaderText="Color ID" SortExpression="ColorID"/>
                    </Columns>
                    <PagerStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    <PagerSettings Mode="NumericFirstLast" />
                </asp:GridView>
```

I would like to click on the row1 diagram below then will prompt out the message Hello world,
if i clicked on Row2 it will to display helloworld2.

```
 __________________________________________________________________
|___Row1__________|_____Row1____|_______Row1_____|_____Row1________|
|___Row2__________|_____Row2____|_______Row2_____|_____Row2________|
|___Row3__________|_____Row3____|_______Row3_____|_____Row3________|
|___Row4__________|_____Row4____|_______Row4_____|_____Row4________|
```

Comment: even this can work.Why you wants to write it on RowDataBound

Comment: This can only work on the Table , but i need apply it on my Gridview ,Sir

Comment: You need to provide a lot more informations, and clearly describe your problem because your issue here is on the details...

Comment: Because my account rate is not enough, so that i could not update the image to explain what i really need. So i just adjust again the question ,try to put more explanation on above.

Answer (score 0):

If you wants to display just alert with rowNumber then it is so simple
Use

> onrowdatabound="CustomersGridView_RowDataBound" for Your gridview

```
<asp:gridview id="CustomersGridView" 
        autogeneratecolumns="true"
        allowpaging="true"
        onrowdatabound="CustomersGridView_RowDataBound" 
        runat="server">
      </asp:gridview>
```

and on Server Side

```
 public void CustomersGridView_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {

     if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {

     e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", "alert('helloworld " + e.Row.RowIndex + "')");
    }

   }
```